# How does Blippy get its data

Tags: python, web-applications, screen-scraping

I was wondering how [Blippy](http://blippy.com/) is able to get my data? It requires me to put in my bank name, bank card number and password, so is it doing a simple website scrape by logging in?

My bank, however also requires a seperate passphrase as well. How does it get around that?

Can urllib and such libraries be used in Python to replicate Blippy functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Blippy probably uses a service like Yodlee to interface with the bank rather that simple screen scraping. Having said that it is possible to implement similar functionality by combining urllib, [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html) and [Regex](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) modules.